# Merge two repositories

Tags: git, merge, bitbucket

I have a repository that's called 'Project B'. Project B is based on a version of Project A. But after the development of Project B a new version of Project A has been released.

I would like to merge the latest version of Project A into Project B. The only problem now is that when pulling Project A into a new branch of Project B all the files are marked as new which results in Merge conflicts on every changed file.

Is there a easy way to solve this problem?

Edit: Added the git commands I used

```
$ git remote add projecta [path-to-.git-in-bitbucket]
$ git pull projecta master
```

Comment: How did you pull project A. Did you add project A as a remote and tried pulling ?

Comment: please show us the git commands which you have used.

Comment: I have edited the comment with the git commands I used

Answer (score 0):

This may be help:
[Merging two git repositories](http://blog.caplin.com/2013/09/18/merging-two-git-repositories/)